# Number of connected components

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph $G$ of $N$ nodes and $E$ edges, we construct new graph $G^{'}$ with $N^2$ nodes of type $(a,b)$. There's an edge between $(a,b)$ and $(a^{'},b^{'})$ in $G'$ iff we have an edge from $a$ to $a^{'}$ and $b$ to $b^{'}$ in $G$ .
We need to find the number of connected components in $G'$.
My work:
We can remove the isloated vertices by counting their contribution to answer, which would be $N^2-(N-isolated)^2$.
Now, I don't know how to move ahead but the answer is based on the number of bipartite and non-bipartite components in $G$, which I am not able to think about.

Comment: Note, the product you are using here is that $G^\prime = G\times G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood how no of bipartite components(say, $bip$) and other components(say, $oth$) come into picture.
Consider a node $(b1,b2)$ in $G'$. Here $b1,b2$ represenet nodes from 2 bipartite components of $G$. It's beautiful to note that all $(white,white)$ and $(black,black)$ nodes form 1 connected component, and all $(white,black)$ and $(black,white)$ form other connected component in $G'$. Therefore, we get total $2*bip^2$ components in $G'$.
Consider a node of type $(bipartite,other)$ or $(other,bipartite)$ in $G'$. Now, nodes formed by their product form a single connected component in $G'$. So we get their contribution as $2*bip*oth$.
Finally consider node of type $(other,other)$. Their contribution will be $oth*oth$ on similar grounds.
So final answer is $N^2-(N-isolated)^2+2bip^2+2.bip.oth+oth^2$